# How to make a template specialization for integral, floating and char* types without if constexpr?

Tags: c++

I need a function `void foo(T &t)` that will have one implementation for `char*`, another for `std::is_integral_v` and yet another for `std::is_floating_point` types.
I don't want to make a constexpr approach because it would create a gigantic function with a lot of branches that are difficult to navigate and understand and scale.
I've tried SFINAE but i can't fully understand how it works

The code i've written before

```cpp
template<typename T>
void foo(T *t);

template<>
void foo<char *>(char **t) { /* does some logic */ } 

template<>
void foo<int>(int *t) { /* does some logic */ } 

template<>
void foo<float>(float *t) { /* does some logic */ }
```

i want to make an `int` specialization to also accept all `int#_t`, `uint#_t` and other integral types
the same i want for my `float` also accept `double` types without copy-pasting implementation with different cast i need a single scalable solution with SFINAE or any other technology

**UPD**
Given answers looks close to what I want but they are still having issues in my case. Generally speaking, i want to make a generic template function without implementation so that could raise an error during compilation and the other i want to map onto my C-style api. Different types of called function should map in different ways (different implementation). I was happy with full-specialization for each type until I had need to reuse the same implementations for a group of related values like `float` and `double` use the same implementations, int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, and their unsigned counterparts should use their own implemetation but the same for each one.
The main requirements are:

- not using if-constexpr
- not having a single place where i need to make changes after adding a new type with its own implementation
- and i want to make use of explicit template parameters (possibly without deducing because i don't trust it well enough)

The api i have is like that:

```
void createString(const char *);
void createInt(int);
void createFloat(float);
void createSomeCustomStuff(CustomStruct);
```

and i want to templatify that on the C++ side with ability to pass `const char *` as a string literal, `uint32_t` into `createInt`, etc like so

```
create<const char *>("hello");
create("world");
create(0ull);
create(double(100));
```

Comment: You cannot partially specialise a function template. You need an overload. The answers below use overloading, not specialisation. (/nitpick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job:

```
// For integral types only:
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>> foo(T *t)
{
    cout << "integer" << endl;
}

// For floating point types only:
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>> foo(T *t)
{
    cout << "floating point" << endl;
}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>> foo(T *t)
{
    cout << "pointer" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    long a;
    double b;
    foo(&a);
    foo(&b);
    const char *c = "test";
    foo(&c);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/b5fT9PGbv

Comment: it looks like if i add new implementation for custom types then i have to add these into the condition of `others` template

Comment: I changed the third function to pointer type. If you do not need a function, which fits all not matched cases, you can skip the others function.

Comment: @Artyer nice idea. After reading the question again I think OP does not need the default case, but it is such a useful idea, that you should post it as an answer. I would upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enable_if`:

```
#include<type_traits>

void foo(char* t) { /* does some logic */ }

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr>
void foo(T* t) { /* does some logic */ }

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>* = nullptr>
void foo(T* t) { /* does some logic */ }
```

Comment: what does the star in front of `= nullptr` mean? Is it possible to also add my custom types?

Comment: could you advice an answer on so may be or the name of the technique you showed. Is it SFINAE? I though that SFINAE looks like `template<typename = enable_if_t<...>>`

Comment: When the condition is met and `enable_if` has no additional parameters, then the `type` of `enable_if` is `void`, adding `*` is to make it `void*` and `= nullptr` is to set the default value. You can refer to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for more details.